# Upgrade tesseract version in linux

Tags: linux, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am very new to linux and I have just started with the basics of it. We have a package called tesseract which has different versions in test and dev environment. I am unable to update the tesseract version as its giving the below

```
apt-get install tesseract-ocr
tesseract-ocr is already the newest version (3.04.01-5)
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed,0 to remove and 1 not upgraded
```

However when I checked the version in dev environment

```
tesseract -v
tesseract 4.1.1
   leptonica-1.78.0
```

Can someone pls help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Which Linux distribution you are using?

Comment: You might want to use ppa's then to get the latest software

Comment: @Linux Geek, I am using centOS

Comment: CentOS 7, tesseract : There is version 4.1.0+git4242 (05-Feb-2021) in the "Alexander_Pozdnyakov.repo" https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Alexander_Pozdnyakov/CentOS_7/ . ..... Besides that, e.g. {leptonica-1.75.3 + tesseract-4.1.1} builds with no errors, CentOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your system with unsupported packages from this untrusted PPA by adding ppa:alex-p/tesseract-ocr-devel to your system's Software Sources

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alex-p/tesseract-ocr-devel

sudo apt update

tesseract --version
```